# Why File.exists() does not work

Tags: java, file-io, getresource

I have a file `watstheday.txt` in my `src/main/resources` folder of my project as shown in the image file below.

[image]

I read the file through a `getResourceAsStream()` method of the `ClassLoader` and perform further actions in my code which is working perfectly.
However if I try to perform a check if the file exists through the below code it always returns false.

```
try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            System.out.println("!@#!@# so difficult to be simple..."+classLoader.getResource("watstheday.txt"));
            //this returns false but the file is there
            System.out.println("@#@ vertigo2 "+new File(classLoader.getResource("watstheday.txt").getFile()).isFile());
            //this ALSO returns false but the file is there
            System.out.println("@#@ vertigo2 "+new File(classLoader.getResource("watstheday.txt").getFile()).exists());
            //Giving the / to mark the root of the application though that's not required
            System.out.println("@#@ vertigo3 "+new File(classLoader.getResource("//watstheday.txt").getFile()).isFile());
            //the below code with getResourceAsStream works absolutely fine and i can read the file
            classLoader.getResourceAsStream("watstheday.txt");
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("watstheday.txt")));
            while (true) {
                lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
                System.out.println(" @@#@ lineJustFetched =" + lineJustFetched);
            }
            buf.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I consulted the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916845/cant-access-to-files-in-resources-directory-with-maven-with-eclipse-ide) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java) before finally putting up this Question  but couldn’t find what am I doing wrong. When I print the file name it gets printed with the complete deployment path shown as

```
!@#!@# so difficult to be simple... vfs=$my_server_deployment_folder_location$/helloworld/watstheday.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible that your file exists in a zip file ?

Comment: fyi i tested your code on my Eclipse and got @#@ vertigo2 true
@#@ vertigo2 true

Comment: Read this post, this explains why `getResource(...).getFile()` does not return something that you can pass to a `java.io.File` constructor, because it's not the same thing: [What's the difference between a Resource, URI, URL, Path and File in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845223/whats-the-difference-between-a-resource-uri-url-path-and-file-in-java)

Comment: File.exists() would return true if your file exists physically as an entity. It always returns false when on a virtual file system.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev i hv tried repeatedly but it's not true for me. I can't see my own folly,

Comment: @Paras the file is not a zip file and when I print the file path it does get printed correctly which I cross check in the deployment server and found it to b correct

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev is it a windows system u r using?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev The file exists in a vfs as mentioned by Paras so exists() or isFile() is returning me false. I guess u must have tried it out in a standalone main application and it would return true then.

Answer (score 2):

Resources are not files. When you develop (say, in an IDE) and haven't packaged the application yet, you may get paths of real files (somewhere in `src/main/resources`).

However when the application is packaged, resources are entries in an archive. They do not exist as files anymore. So do not use `File` with resources.

Comment: file being used as a resource is a pretty common use case. in my case i have kept the file in the resources folder as maven says to and am able to access the file for my read operation through getResourceAsStream (). Only the classLoader.getResource("watstheday.txt").getFile()).exists() fails!

Comment: I wrote about using resource as file, not file as resource.